# Can you escape characters using parameters and executemany?

Tags: python, mysql, parameters, escaping

Does executemany not escape parameterized strings like execute does?

Using Python3 I am attempting to insert a list into mysql.

```
sqlquery = "INSERT INTO vdaytemp (idvoyage,vdaydate,vdaynotes) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
val=("21","2020-04-01","Highway 22(apples are green)")
mycursor.execute(sqlquery, val)
```

This works fine and inserts the text string with parentheses. But if I try and insert a list using executemany it balks.

```
sqlquery = "INSERT INTO vdaytemp (idvoyage,vdaydate,vdaynotes) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
val = [("21","2020-04-01","Highway 22(apples are red)"),("21","2020-04-01","Highway 23(apples are red)")]
mycursor.executemany(sqlquery, val)
```

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py in prepare_for_mysql(self, params)
    624         """
    625         if isinstance(params, (list, tuple)):
--> 626             result = self._cmysql.convert_to_mysql(*params)
    627         elif isinstance(params, dict):
    628             result = {}

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'convert_to_mysql'
```

It does work if I remove the parentheses from the string. Am I going to have to figure out another way to do this?

Comment: There are lots of strings, You mean the parentheses in `(apples are green)`?

Comment: The error indicates that `self._cmysql` is `None`. It sounds like you've somehow disconnected the cursor from the mysql connection.

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere else in your script. Add more context.

Comment: Aaargh. I cut out all the bits above and ran them alone and you are right. They work. I guess I work my way backwards and try and find the error. The rest is just generating a list from emails but...